# PHP paypal ipn listener transaction array

Tags: php, curl, paypal

```
        $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.paypal.com'));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            //TODO
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            //TODO
        }
```

response

```
cmd=_notify-validate&transaction=Array
```

theres more to the response but has you can see the problem is that their is array within the $_POST array. How to encode and stripslashes of array with in array of $_POST?

Comment: Why don't you just use a PayPal IPN class like https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

Answer (score 1):

Arrays within arrays are not handled correctly in PHP through the $_POST variable.

You need to read the raw data directly from the input stream.

Here's some sample code for you.

```
<?php
   $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
   $myPost = array();
   foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval)
      {
      $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
      if (count($keyval) == 2)
         $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
      }
      $_req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
      foreach ($myPost as $key => $value)
         {
         $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
         $_req .= "&$key=$value";
         }

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
//$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($_req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp){
//Something failed
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $_req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

//Success

}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
//Failure to validate
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific about it :) What's failing?. 
Check you PHP config. Sometimes fopen is not enabled to open URL's directly. So if I'm guessing right,  the postback is what might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Paypal given codes - they should work -

https://www.x.com/instant-payment-notification-4

Here is the code for you to copy it easily.

```
<?php

// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
?>
```