# Paypal payment from iOS device to web service (PHP)

Tags: php, ios, web-services, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm trying to sell credits from an iOS App, when I do the payment I get this information to my PHP web service:

```
payment_request_date  -  Tue Jul 17 05:32:19 PDT 2012
return_url  -  http://www.paypal.com
fees_payer  -  EACHRECEIVER
ipn_notification_url  -  http://www.xxxxxx.com/xxx/xxx/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/test.php
verify_sign  -  AgYuiYfIN5owxd-SesPtCf2-3s2qAIwGX.FB6cfxxxxxxxxx
test_ipn  -  1
transaction  -  Array
0  -  EUR 69.00
cancel_url  -  http://www.paypal.com
pay_key  -  AP-1MJ8653xxxxxx
action_type  -  PAY
transaction_type  -  Adaptive Payment PAY
status  -  COMPLETED
log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction  -  false
charset  -  windows-1252
sender_useCredentials  -  true
notify_version  -  UNVERSIONED
reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error  -  false
```

If I want to check if the payment is correct what is the next step to do?

I've been looking through the paypal documentation but it is very confusing.

Thanks in advance.

### **EDIT 2012-07-18:**

Trying to validate the transaction I had a problem with the transaction array so I had to change my script to work like this one here [PHP paypal ipn listener transaction array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388139/php-paypal-ipn-listener-transaction-array) and everything is working now!! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should now validate paypal's receipt and, if successful, unlock the user's credits.
Have a look at the sample code for php at this location:

https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

Please also be aware of the fact that this kind of purchase is disallowed by Apple's AppStore review-guidelines and such an app will be rejected and not be published to the AppStore.

Apple only allows their own In-App-Purchase.